# how to sum up rows selectively in R?

Tags: r

Here is the head of my data sample.

```
         SIZE      OFR       BID    
          1       362.25    361.75    
          1       362.25    361.75    
          3       362.25    361.75    
          4       362.75    362      
          8       362.50    362       
          6       362.50    362       
          12      362.50    362        
          8       362.25    362       
          9       362.25    362       
          11      362.25    362
```

I am trying to implement a for loop to sum up SIZE if `OFR[i]=OFR[i-1] & BID[i]= BID[i-1]`. In the new data frame, there will be fewer rows.

my current coding is:

```
L<-length(mtq$SIZE)
mtq$SIZE1<-c()
for (i in 2:L)
{
   if ( mtq$BID[i] == mtq$BID[i-1] | mtq$OFR[i] == mtq$OFR[i-1])
   {mtq$SIZE1=mtq$SIZE[i]+mtq$SIZE[i-1]}
}
```

it keeps saying that the argument length is 0.

Anyone has any suggestion for me?

Ultimately, What I need is as follows:

```
     SIZE      OFR       BID    SIZE1
      1       362.25    361.75    NA
      1       362.25    361.75    NA
      3       362.25    361.75    5 "(this is from 1+1+3)" 
      4       362.75    362       4
      8       362.50    362       NA
      6       362.50    362       NA
      12      362.50    362       26 "(this is from 8+6+12)"
      8       362.25    362       NA
      9       362.25    362       NA
      11      362.25    362       28 "(8+9+11)"
```

Then I can drop all the NAs and only leave with 4 rows at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
indx <- with(mtq, BID[-1]==BID[-length(BID)] | OFR[-1]==OFR[-length(OFR)] )
mtq$SIZE1 <- with(mtq, c(NA,ifelse(indx, SIZE[-1]+SIZE[-length(SIZE)], NA)))
```

Or  using the `devel` version of data.table i.e. `v1.9.5`.  Instructions to install are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(mtq)[BID==shift(BID)|OFR==shift(OFR), SIZE1 := SIZE+shift(SIZE, fill=0)]
```

#### Update

Based on the expected output

```
 setDT(mtq)[,  SIZE1 := if(.N==1) SIZE  else c(rep(NA, .N-1), sum(SIZE)),
  list(gr=cumsum(shift(BID, fill=FALSE)!= BID|shift(OFR, fill=FALSE)!=OFR))] 
 #SIZE    OFR    BID SIZE1
 #1:    1 362.25 361.75    NA
 #2:    1 362.25 361.75    NA
 #3:    3 362.25 361.75     5
 #4:    4 362.75 362.00     4
 #5:    8 362.50 362.00    NA
 #6:    6 362.50 362.00    NA
 #7:   12 362.50 362.00    26
 #8:    8 362.25 362.00    NA
 #9:    9 362.25 362.00    NA
 #10:  11 362.25 362.00    28
```

#### data

```
 mtq <- structure(list(SIZE = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 12L, 8L, 9L, 
 11L), OFR = c(362.25, 362.25, 362.25, 362.75, 362.5, 362.5, 362.5, 
 362.25, 362.25, 362.25), BID = c(361.75, 361.75, 361.75, 362, 
 362, 362, 362, 362, 362, 362)), .Names = c("SIZE", "OFR", "BID"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: the dataset is in xts form. looks like these coding does not work well with the xts data. any other suggestion that i could receive? thank you so much

Comment: @QuanbiaoShang  Could you update your post with the dput output of the example you posted, i.e. `dput(mtq)`

Comment: @ akrun. Thank you for the help. I converted my data to data.frame and the code worked. However, this code can only sum up two rows once. In my data set, sometimes there are three or more consecutive rows needs to be summed into one based on the applied standard. Is there a way that we can apply this code again and again to let them sum up till no more consecutive two rows meet the requirement, then stop looping. Thank you so very much for the valuable advice.

Comment: @QaunbiaoShang As I mentioned earlier, if you could update your post with a small example describing the problem and the expected output, it would be easier to test

Comment: @ akrun, sorry about the delay. I just edited my question to add a final desired output of the data. Hopefully it was clear, thank you so very much.

Comment: @ akrun, thanks. I poped out a new error:                                              > setDT(mtq)[,  SIZE1 := if(.N==1) SIZE  else c(rep(NA, .N-1), sum(SIZE)),
+            list(gr=cumsum(shift(BID, fill=FALSE)!= BID|shift(OFR, fill=FALSE)!=OFR))]
                                                                                                                Error in shift(BID, fill = FALSE) : unused argument (fill = FALSE)

Comment: @QuanbiaoShang  I am not getting any error with the data you showed.  Try with the data in my post.  I am using the devel version of data.table.  Which version of data.table you have?

Comment: @ akrun, the version of data.table i am using is 1.9.4  "data.table 1.9.4  For help type: ?data.table"  The error still is "shift(BID, fill = FALSE) : unused argument (fill = FALSE) ". I will accept the answer that you provided and figure out what is wrong. thank a lot again

Comment: @QuanbiaoShang  Actually the `shift` is introduced in the devel version. I have added a link where you can find instructions to install the devel version. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation